# JS array.push keeps overwriting

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, for-loop, javascript-objects

I'm trying to pass objects into an array within a for loop. The value keeps getting overwritten.

```
const files = require("./getFiles")();

module.exports = function templating() {
  let design = JSON.parse(files[1]),
    data = JSON.parse(files[2]),
    count = Object.keys(data).length,
    x = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let tempDesign = design,
      tempData = data;
    tempDesign.columns[0].items[0]["url"] = tempData[i].url;
    tempDesign.columns[1].items[0]["text"] = tempData[i].name;
    tempDesign.columns[1].items[1]["text"] = tempData[i].desc;
    tempDesign.columns[1].items[2]["facts"][0]["value"] = tempData[i].priceText;
    tempDesign.columns[1].items[3]["actions"][0]["data"] = tempData[i].price;
    x.push(tempDesign);
  }
  return x;
};
```

I want my output to look something like this :

```
sample= [
    {
     "x":"data",
     "y":"data"
    },
    {
     "a":"data",
     "b":"data"
    },
    {
     "c":"data",
     "d":"data"
    },
    {
     "e":"data",
     "f":"data"
    },
   ]
```

Instead I get this :

```
sample= [
    {
     "e":"data",
     "f":"data"
    },
    {
     "e":"data",
     "f":"data"
    },
    {
     "e":"data",
     "f":"data"
    },
    {
     "e":"data",
     "f":"data"
    }
   ]
```

The loop pushes only the last object to the array but with the right count.

Comment: `let tempdesign = design` does not create a copy but only a *reference*. Thus, it's pointing at the same object. and so you are pushing (and modifying) the same object over and over again ...

Comment: I'm new to coding. Could you help me by correcting the syntax please?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Got it corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here:

```js
let tempDesign = design,
```

will create a *reference* to the variable `design`. (In case you don't know what a reference is, think of it as an alternative name to an existing variable). Later, after you modify the contents of `tempDesign`, you push it to the array. The new array element holds a reference to `design`.

Now, if we look at the next (possible) iteration of your for-loop, the new variable `tempDesign` is another reference to the same variable `design`, which is already referred to by the 1st element in the array `x`, and that is pushed to the array!  And so, every next iteration of your for-loop pushes another, duplicate reference to the array `x`, all of which refer to the same variable `design`.

The fix is to make a **copy** of the variable `design` to avoid creating the showcased reference "maze". There are multiple methods of cloning objects in JavaScript, but this simple yet effective method should do the trick in your use case:

```js
let tempDesign = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(design));
```

This will make a new variable `tempDesign`, which is an object on its own, and thus isn't a reference to `design` anymore, while holding all data originally contained in `design`.

Comment: This helped, thanks a ton.